# Django: How to add the last added date to a query set using ListView

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-3.1

I don't know how to create the queryset so that the last `URLusage` table entry is picked up for each URL in the `RedirectURL` table  `dateaccessed` field and appends it to the query results similar to what I did with the `num_links` field.

The end result is that I display a list of RedirectURL's with the usage count and last date used from the `URLusage` table.

Thank you.

eg.

**Link---Last Used---Total Use**

xxxxx  13 Dec 2020  22

yyyyy  14 Jan 2020  2

**Models**

```
class RedirectURL(models.Model):
    userid = models.PositiveBigIntegerField(null=True, default=1)
    srcurl = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, unique=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(null=True, default=False)

class URLusage(models.Model):
    redirectid = models.ForeignKey(RedirectURL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)       
    dateaccessed = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
```

**View**

```
class LinksList(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    login_url = "home"
    redirect_field_name = None
    login_required = True
    context_object_name = 'links'
    paginate_by = 30
    template_name = 'yourlinks.html'
    paginate_orphans = 1

    def get_queryset(self):
        return RedirectURL.objects.filter(userid=self.request.user.id, active=True).annotate(num_links=Count('urlusage')).order_by('-id')

    def get_context_data(self,*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return super(LinksList,self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs) 
        except Http404:
            self.kwargs['page'] = 1
            return super(LinksList,self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
```

**Template**

```
{% for i in links %}
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm">
            {{ i.srcurl }}      
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm">
            {{ i.last_dateaccessed }}
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm">
            {{ i.num_links }}
          </div>
        </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need a `queryset` like this:

```
from django.db.models import Max, Count

qs = RedirectURL.objects.annotate(last_used=Max('urlusage__dateaccessed'), total_used=Count('urlusage'))
```

which will group your urls by `redirect_id` and returns your desired results.
Then you can iterate through `qs` and show your data:

```
for rec in qs:
    print(rec.srcurl, rec.last_used, rec.total_used)
```

Or you can pass `qs` to your template context and then use this data in your related template.

Note: You can also filter this `queryset` based on your requirements. For example filtering based on user:

```
qs = RedirectURL.objects.filter(user=some_user).annotate(last_used=Max('urlusage__dateaccessed'), total_used=Count('urlusage'))
```

.